# Generating Loops and Arrays from User Input and Printing Looped Output

Tags: javascript, html

I am editing an existing html file. I have to add a numeric entry field allowing users to indicate the number of volunteers they want to enter information for, and upon pressing enter in said field, generate additional input fields in the form below. Then when the form is submitted, the text on the bottom will replace the placeholders with the text entered in the form and repeated for as many volunteers were indicated in the first field.

I am new to javascript so there's still a lot of things I don't really understand but I am trying to learn. I have attempted referencing similar isolated examples of each action I need to perform but none of it really comes together or works properly for me. I understand that I should be using loop and array functions but can't really piece together how it all connects.

I have the code for the number field as well as the javascript for the text that will get replaced so far notated below:

```js
function changeText() {
  var recipient = document.getElementById('recipient').value;
  document.getElementById('recipientName').innerHTML = recipient;
  var organization = document.getElementById('organization').value;
  document.getElementById('organizationName').innerHTML = organization;
  var date = document.getElementById('date').value;
  document.getElementById('eventDate').innerHTML = date;
  var url = document.getElementById('url').value;
  document.getElementById('websiteURL').innerHTML = url;
  var host = document.getElementById('host').value;
  document.getElementById('hostName').innerHTML = host;
  return false;
}
```

```css
body {
  font: 15px arial, sans-serif;
  color: #808080;
}

input[type=text],
select,
input[type=password],
radio {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 12px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

input[type=submit] {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #800D1E;
  color: white;
  padding: 14px 20px;
  margin: 8px 0;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 4px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

input[type=submit]:hover {
  background-color: #802F1E;
}

section {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  padding: 20px;
}

article {
  border-radius: 5px;
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  padding: 20px;
  color: #222222;
}

ul.topnav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

ul.topnav li {
  float: left;
}

ul.topnav li a {
  display: block;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 14px 16px;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul.topnav li a:hover:not(.active) {
  background-color: #111;
}

ul.topnav li a.active {
  background-color: #CCCCCC;
  color: #333
}

ul.topnav li.right {
  float: right;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul.topnav li.right,
  ul.topnav li {
    float: none;
  }
}

.top {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  height: 68px;
  padding-top: 20px;
  line-height: 50px;
  overflow: hidden;
  z-index: 2;
}

.logo {
  font-family: arial;
  text-decoration: none;
  line-height: 1;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
  font-size: 37px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
  color: #555555;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 17px;
}

.logo .dotcom {
  color: #800D1E
}

.topnav {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: #5f5f5f;
  color: #f1f1f1;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.top .logo {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: left;
  margin: auto
}

footer {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  padding: 1rem;
  background-color: #efefef;
  text-align: center;
}

div.gallery {
  margin: 5px;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  float: left;
  width: 180px;
}

div.gallery:hover {
  border: 1px solid #777;
}

div.gallery img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

div.desc {
  padding: 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">

<head>
  <title>Invitation Page</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="top">
      <a class="logo" href="index.html">Volunteers<span class="dotcom">.org</span></a>
    </div>
    <nav>
      <ul class="topnav">
        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="invitation.html" class="active">Invitation</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="gallery.html">Gallery</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="registration.html">Registration</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  </header>
  <br/>
  <label for="volunteeramount">Number of Volunteers:</label>
  <input type="number" name="volunteeramount" id="volunteers" placeholder="#" min="1" max="10">
  <section id="pageForm">
    <form action="#" onsubmit="return false;">
      <br/>
      <label for="recipientName">Recipient Name:</label>
      <input type="text" name="recipientName" id="recipient" placeholder="Enter your Recipient Name" />

      <label for="organizationName">Organization Name:
            </label>
      <input type="text" name="organizationName" id="organization" placeholder="Enter your Organization Name" />

      <label for="eventDate">Event Date:
            </label>
      <input type="text" name="eventDate" id="date" placeholder="Enter your Event Date" />

      <label for="websiteURL">URL:
            </label>
      <input type="text" name="websiteURL" id="url" placeholder="Enter your Website URL" />

      <label for="hostName">Host Name:
            </label>
      <input type="text" name="hostName" id="host" placeholder="Host Name" />

      <input type="submit" value="Submit" onclick="changeText()">
    </form>
  </section>

  <article id="placeholderContent">
    Hello <span id="recipientName">recipientName</span>!
    <br/>
    <br/> You have been invited to volunteer for an event held by <span id="organizationName">organizationName</span> on <span id="eventDate">eventDate</span>. Please come to the following website: <span id="websiteURL">websiteURL</span> to sign up as
    a volunteer.
    <br/>
    <br/> Thanks!
    <br/>
    <br/>
    <span id="hostName">hostName</span>
  </article>
</body>

</html>
```

Any help would be appreciated in advance. I'm not sure if I should include any other information but please let me know if I do, I will try to provide what I can. Thank you.